Chrome 125. Elements are jumping. Why?
After the update to Chrome 125.0.6422.142 (64-bit), in some cases the elements started jumping. For example, in the snippet below when hovering. Please tell me what this is about and how to fix it?
In older Chrome versions everything is ok.


*, ::before, ::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: contain;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: transform .35s;
    width: 81px;
    height: 53px;
}

.coin {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 51px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9CeiTPT1QNO0MG0VSpIXDKn80XXs8rTaDAA&s);
    transition: transform .3s;
}

.coin2 {
    top: -7px;
    left: 156px;
}

.button:hover .coin2,
.button:active .coin2 {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
<div class="button">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="coin"></div>
    <div class="coin coin2"></div>
  </div>
</div>




Looks like a browser bug. So unless someone happened to know/find a workaround, you probably can't do much else other than wait, until it gets fixed in a future release.

This is not happening on Microsoft Edge Version 125.0.2535.85 (Official build ( claims to be uptodate ) (64-bit) but is on Chrome Version 125.0.6422.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) [both on Windows10). May be worth reporting.

Just noticed it isn't jumping if I run the code direct from a file on the laptop - so is there something related to the snippet being in an iframe?? What context are you running the code in?

This is very strange. Not a full explanation but a possible workaround:
Giving the .button a background color other than transparent seems to stop the jumping.
This snippet sets background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.01);
On my Chrome I see no jumping but if I set the alpha channel to 0 I see jumping (and the jumping seems to be to set the coins as if the button didn't exist, or at least as tho' its position left didn't).


*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: contain;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform .35s;
  width: 81px;
  height: 53px;
}

.coin {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 51px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9CeiTPT1QNO0MG0VSpIXDKn80XXs8rTaDAA&s);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.coin2 {
  top: -7px;
  left: 156px;
}

.button:hover .coin2,
.button:active .coin2 {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
<div class="button">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="coin"></div>
    <div class="coin coin2"></div>
  </div>
</div>




There are many workarounds like settings these properties to .coin:
backface-visibility: hidden or transform: translateZ(0) or some z-index.
I think there are a few more, but in a large ready-made project, it is difficult to edit like this. It looks like there won't be a simple solution until Chrome is updated.

Do  you know why it happens? And in particular why it happens in the snippet system here but not on a simple file? Is there something to do with layers?
